# How to use javascript on elements in a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

Here is a scenario: 
From **create.jsp**, I am creating a play button and an audio tag as follows:

```
//play button
out.write("<input type=\"button\" id=\"playButton\" value=\"Play Now\" >");
out.write("");

//audio element
out.write("<audio id=\"sound\" preload=\"auto\">");
//out.write("<source src=\"sfl\" type=\"audio/ogg\" />");
out.write("<source src=\"sfl\" type=\"audio/mpeg\" />");
out.write("Your browser does not support the audio element.");
out.write("</audio>");
```

I used a frame to bring this to **home.jsp** as follows:

```
<iframe id='bgframe' style='display:compact;' src='create.jsp' width="400" height="200"></iframe>
```

In my jquery code, I have

```
    $("#playButton").click(function(){
    alert("Play button clicked");
    }
```

But nothing happens when I click the playButton.

Question:  How can I use jquery or javascript to capture click event on playbutton deployed via a frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
out.write("<script>function(){//your code here}</script>");
out.write("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"demo()"\ id=\"playButton\" value=\"Play Now\" >");
```

or

```
out.write("<script src="file name where code is placed"></script>");
out.write("<input type=\"button\" id=\"playButton\" value=\"Play Now\" >");
```

Comment: Ok. Trying it out... 1 sec pls.

Comment: Here's an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: and here's the code as outputed in Chrome error debug sources: <script src="c_script.js"></script><input type="button" id="playBt" value="Play Now" ><audio id="sound" preload="auto"><source src="sfl" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>

<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#playBt").click(function(){
          alert("Button is clicked");
      }  
</script>

Answer (score 0):

By design, JavaScript from a parent frame cannot act on elements contained within an iframe.

Comment: oh really?  So what can I do now?

Comment: I don't think this is true. If the page in the frame is on the same domain (i.e. there's no cross-domain security issues), you should be able to access the DOM of the page in the iFrame. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page).

Comment: I stand corrected. I must've never tried same-domain before, and assumed it was the same as cross-domain. However, @bdfios, you should consider using the JSP equivalent of partial views over an iframe here; it looks like that would fit your use case and would 1) make your life easier, and 2) reduce HTTP requests.

Comment: @Richard - Thanks for the link.  I am getting some information there

Comment: @ehdv - sorry, can you explain what you mean by "JSP equivalent of partial views over an iframe"?  I am definitely open to trying out your suggestion once I understand it.

Comment: In C# / ASP.NET, there is a notion of a partial view, which the server renders inline in the page before sending it to the client. This means that there isn't a second HTTP request, and your JS is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `contents()`

```
$("#bgframe").contents().find("#playButton").click(function(){
    alert("Play button clicked");
}
```